# Mount a Logical Volume

Tags: centos, filesystems

My VPS was initially setup without allocating all 80g of diskspace. I successfully ran fdisk /dev/sda, allocated the space (sda3), wrote partition table, rebooted, and ran pvcreate /dev/sda3.

My question now is how do I mount this new volume? I got lost in the docs after I created the group.

```
==>vgcreate vg3 /dev/sda3
```

I just want to mount /backup on /dev/sda3.

```
==>lsblk -a
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0               2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda               8:0    0   80G  0 disk 
├─sda1            8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot
├─sda2            8:2    0 19.8G  0 part 
│ ├─vg0-lv_swap 253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
│ └─vg0-lv_root 253:1    0 17.8G  0 lvm  /
└─sda3            8:3    0   60G  0 part 
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Do you want to use `vg3` for backup? If so, you need to create an `lv` and then a mountpoint for it at `/backup` and mount it there. Post the output of `vgdisplay` for more information on what you've set up.

Comment: I created an lv "lvcreate -l 100%VG -n lv_bkup vg3". I added an fstab entry "/dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup /backup                 xfs     noatime         0 0" but "mount -a" fails with wrong fs type.

Comment: Did you create an `xfs` filesystem on `/dev/sda3` first?

Comment: I ran "mkfs.ext4 vg3-lv_bkup" changed fstab entry to "/dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup /backup   ext4  defaults       0  0" still get wrong fstype with mount -a .

Comment: I made a mistake about where to create the filesystem. It should be created on the `lv`. Answer below is edited.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to delete the logical volume and remove `/dev/sda3` from `vg3`.

`lvremove /dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup`

`vgreduce vg3 /dev/sda3`

Then, add it to the volume group and proceed with creating and mounting the logical volume again and then create the filesystem.

`vgextend vg3 /dev/sda3`

`lvcreate -l 100%VG -n lv_bkup vg3`

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup`

In `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup /backup ext4 defaults 0 0
```

`mount -a`

`df -h` will show it mounted.

Comment: vgextend gives msg: "WARNING: xfs signature detected on /dev/sda3 at offset 0. Wipe it? [y/n]: " I entered yes. lvcreate worked but mount still gives bad fs type. I also reverted back to pvremove. No luck. The Hosting Provider suggest I rebuild/wipe the server to get the space.

Comment: See my update. I apologize for the mistake about where to create the filesystem.

Comment: OK. Got It. Change mkfd.xfs to mkfs.ext4 and it works. However I did revert back with vgremove and pvremove. Success was pvcreate, vgcreate, lvcreate, mkfs.ext4, edit fstab, and mount.

Comment: Cool. You can accept my answer now that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not create a filesystem on `/dev/sda3` if you're planning to use it with LVM.

Also, since your system has the other LVs on this disk in `vg0`, it might be better to extend that volume group instead of creating a new one. That way, if you some day need to extend your root LV, you can use some of the capacity of `/dev/sda3` if it's not completely occupied by the new LV yet (or you could shrink or delete the new LV first). But perhaps you have other VGs you have not described, and you'd use this new space to extend one of them instead.

Your `/dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup` is failing because you don't have created a filesystem *on the LV*. The filesystem you may have created before `vgcreate` or `vgextend` was overwritten with the LVM PV headers when you did that.

Before mounting the new LV for the first time, you'll need to do either `mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/vg3-lv_backup` or `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/vg3-lv_bkup` depending on which filesystem type you wish to use.

Comment: I did make a mistake in where to create the filesystem but if he wants to use the new space for backups, it might be better for him to create a separate volume group for it rather than extending the existing volume group.

Comment: Creating a separate LV is enough to separate the backups from the other data. Having the separate PVs on the same disk within the same VG allows more flexible management of disk space, should there be need for it in the future (if the filesystems allow, e.g. you could shrink an ext4 backup filesystem and use the reduced space to enlarge the root filesystem). If you set up a new VG, resizing will be much more complicated.

Comment: That all depends. If he's able to get more disk space for his VPS, then adding space won't be a problem regardless of the two separate volume groups. If he wants to resize one and move the space elsewhere then it will be more complicated. It all depends on what's available.